# Unity 2D collision between objects C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm just starting out with learning Unity. I'm trying to create a simple verticle spaceshooter. I have attached a script for my spaceship to fire bullets. There seems to be something either wrong with the object collision setup or code where I can't seem to destroy the object my bulletprefab collides with. This is the current script for my firebullets:

```
public class BulletFiring : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public float bulletSpeed = 20f;
    public float bulletLifetime = 3f; // Lifetime of the bullet before despawning

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Check for input to fire bullets
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            FireBullet();
        }
    }

    void FireBullet()
    {
        // Instantiate a bullet at the spaceship's position
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        Rigidbody2D bulletRigidbody = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        bulletRigidbody.velocity = transform.up * bulletSpeed;

        // Despawn
        StartCoroutine(DespawnBulletAfterDelay(bullet, bulletLifetime));
    }

    IEnumerator DespawnBulletAfterDelay(GameObject bullet, float delay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        Destroy(bullet);
    }

rigidbody2D/collider2D
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision detected with object tagged as: " + collision.gameObject.tag);
        // Check if the collided object is not tagged as "Player" and it's not a bullet
        if (!collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && !collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Bullet"))
        {
            // Destroy the collided object
            Debug.Log("Bullet collided with: " + collision.gameObject.name);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

I have created some debug logs, when I play the game I can clearly see the bullets colliding with objects however it doesn't register on my console, nor does it destroy the objects. My bulletprefab and objects have rigidbody2d as well as circlecollider2d. All objects are untagged apart from the spaceship(player) and bulletprefab(bullet). If it helps whenever I fire bullet my console registers the fact that my bullet is colliding with itself on fire:

```
Collision detected with object tagged as: Bullet
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
BulletFiring:OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D) (at Assets/BulletFiring.cs:45)
```

I'm assuming something is wrong with my bullet prefab. Can anyone help me with diagnosing the problem?

Comment: what is the line rigidbody2D/collider2D in your code for? are you sure there isnt your prefab already spawned where the bullets supposed to appear so it clashes on arival?

Comment: I am sorry that is my mistake, I was testing some code and I didn't erase the rigidbody2D/collider2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your naming and description I assume the following

- This script is attached to your player. It spawns bullets
- You rather wanted to detect the collision of your **bullets** with samething else

Currently you are detecting the collision of something with your player that has this spawner script attached.

You probably rather wanted to have this on your bullet prefab itself

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerilaizeField] private Rigidbody2D _rb;

    public void Initialize(Vector2 direction)
    {
        if(!_rb) _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        _rb.velocity = direction;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (!collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && !collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Bullet"))
        {
            // Destroy the collided object
            Debug.Log("Bullet collided with: " + collision.gameObject.name);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class BulletFiring : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Bullet bulletPrefab;

    ...

    void FireBullet()
    {
        // Instantiate a bullet at the spaceship's position
        var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        bullet.Initilaize(transform.up * bulletSpeed);

        // Sidenote: Destroy (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) already has a second optional
        // parameter for providing a delay.
        // Your Coroutine is quite redundant and only increases complexity.
        Destroy(bullet.gameObject, bulletLifetime);
    }
```

And make sure your tags are setup correctly.

Or, I would actually prefer to not use `CompareTag` for this but rather ensure the collisions are correctly set up based on [layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) in your [Physics2D settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html) in the first place so the objects only interact with the desired objects at all.